# How to change the border in CKEditor plugin

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, ckeditor

I have a header and border with a single line then I will edit the document in ckeditor plugin then header has been changed the double line border. I want the solution for it.

Comment: Simple : use CSS

Comment: As simple as that

Comment: You have css to change that requirements